# Insert conflict with foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, orm, foreign-keys, rdbms, ormlite-servicestack

I am building an API with [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) from [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).

---

When populating it with test data I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Order_Customer_CustomerId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "C:\USERS\ALECTAYLOR\SOCIALBOOTSTRAPAPI\SRC\SOCIALBOOTSTRAPAPI\APP_DATA\USERAUTH.MDF",
>   table "dbo.Customer", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

Code (lines 213-236 + CreateOrders function): http://pastebin.com/Njhz7sD2

Profiler output: http://fiddle.jshell.net/cTen2/1/show/

---

Thanks for any advice on how to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, got it to work.

Needed to set the `ShopId` of `Order` and `orderId` of the `orderDetails` `List`.

http://pastebin.com/TbrW150T

Answer (score 0):

FOREIGN KEY constraint generally means that you are trying to insert a value into a table that doesn't exist in the reference table. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx) article on Foreign Keys for more info about what they are and how they work. You need to have a look at the actual structure of the data tables order and customer.

I would guess that you are inserting a customerId into the orders table that doesn't exist in the customers table.

Comment: The customerId has to exist in the customers table since I am accessing it directly from the list when constructing the order: `CustomerId = Customers[0].Id`

Comment: Having a look at your trace it doesn't make a lot of sense as to why you are getting the error, however the only time I have seen that error is when the data doesn't exist for the foreign key (i.e. you are inserting a customerId that doesn't exist in the customer table). As someone else mentioned here could you have a transaction that is not committed yet?

Answer (score 0):

since this is the insert that's failing, the only logical explanation is that customer number 1 doesn't exist. I saw that you insert 3 customers a few lines before. Maybe the transaction was not committed between the moment the customers were inserted and the order is inserted.

> INSERT INTO "Order" ("CustomerId", "ShopId", "ShippingAddress",
>   "OrderDate", "RequiredDate", "ShippedDate", "Total") VALUES (1, 0,
>   '{line1:440 Crescent St, line2:South Melbourne, postCode:7416,
>   city:Melbourne, country:Australia}', '20120430 07:43:18.686', NULL,
>   NULL, 0);

Try to commit the insert after you insert the clients and before you insert the orders